# Click nested elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, onclick

Using only JavaScript, I want to create five nested divs. When clicking one of them, I want that **only that div**'s background to change its color (according to an array of colors).

My problem here is that, because the divs are nested, clicking on any one of them will just color the largest one (the parent). The rest of the code is okay because if I struggle to click on a border, I can actually achieve what I want. But the idea is to work when clicking inside of the smaller div.

```
var currentParent = document.body;
var colors = ['red', 'black', 'green', 'pink', 'purple']
var divArray = []

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let currentDiv = document.createElement("div")
    currentDiv.style.width = `${(i * 10 + 20)}px`
    currentDiv.style.height = `${(i * 10 + 20)}px`
    currentDiv.position = i
    currentParent.append(currentDiv)
    divArray.push(currentDiv)
    currentParent = currentDiv
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    divArray[i].onclick = function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = colors [this.position]
    }
}
```

Comment: look into `event.stopPropagation`, and learn about event "bubbling".  See e.g. https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: You can use stopPropagation to prevent event bubbling to parents but will need more advanced css if you want the children of the one you click unchanged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each loop, a DIV larger than its parent is appended. This means that only the last div can be clicked because it covers the others.

If the sizing logic is reversed so that the DIVs become smaller each loop, the code will work as you expect.

Use `event.stopPropagation();` to prevent the event from bubbling to the other elements.

```js
var currentParent = document.body;
var colors = ['red', 'black', 'green', 'pink', 'purple']
var divArray = []

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let currentDiv = document.createElement("div")
    currentDiv.style.width = `${(60 - i * 10)}px`
    currentDiv.style.height = `${(60 - i * 10)}px`
    currentDiv.position = i
    currentParent.append(currentDiv)
    divArray.push(currentDiv)
    currentParent = currentDiv
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    divArray[i].onclick = function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        this.style.backgroundColor = colors [this.position]
    } 
}
```

```css
div {
  outline: 1px solid orange;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [stop event Propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) on the `onclick` event, like so

```
divArray[i].onclick = function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  this.style.backgroundColor = colors [this.position]
}
```

There is also [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault), to prevent the default behaviors, like a link or form button for example.

```js
var currentParent = document.body;
var colors = ['red', 'black', 'green', 'pink', 'purple']
var divArray = []

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let currentDiv = document.createElement("div")
    currentDiv.style.width = `${(i * 10 + 20)}px`
    currentDiv.style.height = `${(i * 10 + 20)}px`
    currentDiv.position = i
    currentParent.append(currentDiv)
    divArray.push(currentDiv)
    currentParent = currentDiv
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    divArray[i].onclick = function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = colors [this.position]
    }
}
```

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure it's a css problem, check the positions of your divs, if you are using `position:absolute` or `position:relative` check the `z-index` ... I can't tell without your css, but from the js the divs are getting bigger and bigger, in a way that the last div cover the precedent one (you can't click the precedent div) ... edited my answer to illustrate the issue